# Is $\sup(f^2(x))=(\sup(f(x))^2$ if the image of $f$ is non negative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is $\sup(f^2(x))=(\sup(f(x))^2$ if the image of $f$ is non negative? I know the relation is false if the image of $f$ is allowed to take both negative and positive values as we can make the maximum negative value way larger than the positive value, but the relation seems to hold if we only require the image be positive or at the very least, non negative.

Comment: Have you been able to show that one or the other is greater than or equal to the other? I think writing out the definitions in a situation like this will ultimately lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \geq 0$.

Then, $f^2(x) \leq (\sup f(x))^2 \, \forall x$. Hence, $\sup f^2(x) \leq (\sup f(x))^2$.

On the other hand, $f^2(x) \leq \sup f^2(x) \, \forall x$. Hence, $(\sup f(x))^2 \leq \sup f^2(x)$.

So, you get the equality.

Note that it all depends on the fact that $a \leq b \iff a^2 \leq b^2 \, \forall a,b \geq 0$.

Comment: When you say "on the other hand..." did you use the following: from $f^2(x) \le \sup f^2(x)$, since $f \ge 0$ taking the root it is $f(x)\le \sqrt{\sup f^2(x)}$, so taking the supremum it is $\sup f(x) \le \sup \sqrt{\sup f^2(x)}=\sqrt{\sup f^2(x)}$ (latter equality because $\sqrt{\sup f(x)}$ is now a fixed number, so its supremum on any set is itself) and so, again since all is $\ge 0$, squaring it is $(\sup f(x))^2 \le \sup f^2(x)$?

Comment: @ZaWarudo Yes, those will be the proper steps if you want to break it down.